# How to install LLVM 12 for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I currently hold `llvm-9` on Ubuntu `16.04`.

I want to install `llvm-12` alongside with it.

```
sudo apt-get install llvm-12*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package llvm-12*
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'llvm-12*'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'llvm-12*'
```

How can I do it?

Comment: That version is end of standard support in a few days.

Comment: @David, I still insist on that version.

Comment: That of course is up to up. Can I recommend when it is open to sign up on April 30 you get the free ESM so you still get security patches.

Answer (score 11):

You can install `llvm-12` as follows:

```
printf "deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-12 main" |sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/llvm-toolchain-xenial-12.list
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key |sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install llvm-12
```